# Dart compare list and remove if List item occurrence is more than given value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm working on flutter and stuck at one point while comparing two lists. So, Basically what I want to achieve is I have 2 List to compare `mainTimingList` this list contains all dateTime means from 6am to 8pm (half an hour apart) and `bookedTiming` contains only booked timing and it may contain the same timing twice or thrice below I have added both lists. So I want to create a new list by comparing these two if bookedTiming contains the same timing more than 2 or 3 then it'll remove that time for example `bookedTiming` contains `"2021-05-07 12:30:00.000"` twice so this should be removed from `mainTimingList` and append in `output`.

```
var mainTimingList = [
    "2021-05-08 09:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 09:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 10:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 10:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 11:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 11:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 12:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 12:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 13:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 13:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 14:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 14:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 15:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 15:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 16:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 16:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 17:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-08 17:30:00.000"
];
var bookedTiming = [
    "2021-05-07 12:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-07 11:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-07 12:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-07 12:00:00.000",
    "2021-05-07 12:30:00.000",
    "2021-05-07 11:00:00.000"
];

List output = [];
var map = Map();
```

This is what I have done so far with no luck

```
bookedTiming
  .forEach((x) => map[x] = !map.containsKey(x) ? (1) : (map[x] + 1));
for (final e in mainTimingList) {
    bool found = false;
    for (final f in bookedTiming) {
        if (e == f ) {
           found = true;
           break;
        } 
    }
    if (!found) {
        output.add(e);
    } 
 }
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated

Comment: to be clear: you have list `main = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4]` and `booked = [1, 2, 5]` so what output do you expect?

Comment: @pskink thanks for your comment `main =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` (main doesn't have repeated item) and `booked = [1,2,3,2,3,3]` so if 2 and 3 from booked is more than twice so it should be removed and added in new list `output'

Comment: @pskink the output should be `[1,4,5,6,7]` `2` and `3` should be removed and as 1 is single time so it should also stay in output

Comment: `final main = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
final booked = [1,2,3,2,3,3];

final output = booked.groupListsBy((e) => e)
.values.where((e) => e.length > 1)
.map((e) => e.first)
.toList();
main.removeWhere((e) => output.contains(e));
print(main);
print(output);
`

Comment: @pskink I got this error The method 'groupListsBy' isn't defined for the type 'List'. I tried to fix it but seems it's not working

Comment: add `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Comment: sure, your welcome